# Sort in alpha order by those that are not prefaced by APPLE and then those that are prefaced with APPLE

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb.net, icomparer

I have a grid with following values

Arts and Craft

Culture

Bowling

Science and Technology

APPLE - Awesome

APPLE - Healthy

APPLE - Interests

APPLE - Nutrients

I'm trying to use comparer but not able to get this to work. Please assist.

```
Private Function Compare (ByVal x as Object, ByVal y as Object) as Integer Implements Compare

    Dim xCell As String = CType(x, String)
    Dim yCell As String = CType(y, String)
    Dim x1, y1 As Integer

    Dim xReturnVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim xCollection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(xCell, "^IAPPLE\s")

    For Each m As Match In xCollection
        xReturnVal += If(m.ToString() = "", "0", "1")
    Next

    If Not xReturnVal = "" Then
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(xReturnVal)
    End If

    Dim yReturnVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim yCollection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(xCell, "^(?!IAPPLE).+")

    For Each mt As Match In yCollection
        yReturnVal += If(mt.ToString() = "", "0", "1")
    Next

    If Not yReturnVal = "" Then
        y1 = Convert.ToInt32(yReturnVal)
    End If

    'Return yReturnVal.CompareTo(xReturnVal)

    Return y1.CompareTo(x1)

End Function
```

Comment: I don't think you need regular expression here. If only one of the strings end with APPLE then return 1 or -1. Then, just compare the two string.

Comment: Can you provide me with a corrected snippet?

Comment: You can use `Linq` to split the data into two Lists, sort them separately and then join them again.

Comment: Hi, by default I'm getting in alpha order. When user hits sort, that is when I need to sort it. Can you provide me with a working snippet using IComparer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_IComparer_1_Compare__0__0_) class for both String and Object types.
(`VB.Net` and `C#`. I don't know what's the preferred one).

The comparison is simple:

- If both `Objects` | `Strings` contain `"APPLE"`, they're ordered as usual.
- The same if the two compared elements do not contain `"APPLE"`
- If one of the two elements contains `"APPLE"`, it always loses.

Here, I'm using  `[List<Type>].Sort(new [ComparerClass]());`, but it can be used with other methods.
A `LINQ` substitute:

```
string[] input = new string[] { "APPLE - Interests", "Arts and Craft", "Science and Technology", "Culture",
                                "APPLE - Nutrients", "APPLE - Awesome", "Bowling", "APPLE - Healthy"};

string[] SortedApples = input.OrderBy(apple => apple, new AppleComparer()).ToArray();
```

Edit: Changed `Contains()` with `StartsWith()`. Probably better here.

**`C#`** version

```
public class AppleComparer : IComparer<string>, IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (!x.StartsWith("APPLE") & !y.StartsWith("APPLE")) {
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
        else if (x.StartsWith("APPLE") & !y.StartsWith("APPLE")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!x.StartsWith("APPLE") & y.StartsWith("APPLE")) {
            return -1;
        }
        else { return x.CompareTo(y); }
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can be used this way:

```
List<object> ApplesAndCo = new List<object>();
//Or
List<string> ApplesAndCo = new List<string>();
ApplesAndCo.AddRange(new[] { "APPLE - Interests", "Arts and Craft", "Science and Technology", "Culture",
                             "APPLE - Nutrients", "APPLE - Awesome", "Bowling", "APPLE - Healthy"});

ApplesAndCo.Sort(new AppleComparer());
```

**`VB.Net`** version.

```vb
Public Class AppleComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)
    Implements IComparer(Of Object)

    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        If (Not x.StartsWith("APPLE")) And (Not y.StartsWith("APPLE")) Then
            Return x.CompareTo(y)
        ElseIf x.StartsWith("APPLE") And Not y.StartsWith("APPLE") Then
            Return 1
        ElseIf Not x.StartsWith("APPLE") And y.StartsWith("APPLE") Then
            Return -1
        Else
            Return x.CompareTo(y)
        End If
    End Function
    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Object).Compare
        Return Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString())
    End Function
End Class
```

Some thing for `VB.Net`:

```vb
Dim ApplesAndCo As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
'Or as a list og String
'Dim ApplesAndCo As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

ApplesAndCo.AddRange({"APPLE - Interests", "Arts and Craft", "Science and Technology", "Culture",
                      "APPLE - Nutrients", "APPLE - Awesome", "Bowling", "APPLE - Healthy"})

ApplesAndCo.Sort(New AppleComparer())
```

Comment: This Worked. Thank you Jimi.

Comment: @Brian  Glad it was helpful. Check whether the `OrderByDescending()` method is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

By request a snippet that sorts the values using `Linq`.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("Arts and Craft");
list.Add("APPLE - Nutrients");
list.Add("Science and Technology");
list.Add("Culture");
list.Add("APPLE - Interests");
list.Add("APPLE - Awesome");
list.Add("Bowling");
list.Add("APPLE - Healthy");

var sortedList = list.Where(x => x.Substring(0, 5) != "APPLE").OrderBy(y => y)
                   .Concat(list.Where(x => x.Substring(0, 5) == "APPLE").OrderBy(y => y));
```

**VB**

Used https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ to translate the above C# code, so it may not be 100% accurate.

```
Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

list.Add("Arts and Craft")
list.Add("APPLE - Nutrients")
list.Add("Science and Technology")
list.Add("Culture")
list.Add("APPLE - Interests")
list.Add("APPLE - Awesome")
list.Add("Bowling")
list.Add("APPLE - Healthy")

Dim sortedList As var = list.Where(() => {  }, (x.Substring(0, 5) <> "APPLE")).OrderBy(() => {  }, y)
                          .Concat(list.Where(() => {  }, (x.Substring(0, 5) = "APPLE")).OrderBy(() => {  }, y))
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the snippet. But I doubt if I can use this list in my ViewModel. I already have the list collection bound in alpha order(in my Question) via viewModel on Load. I would like to know how to fix this using IComparer.